# Android WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark recreates activity

Tags: android, webkit, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

I'm trying to make a webView use the dark theme by using `implementation "androidx.webkit:webkit:1.2.0-alpha01"`and this:

```
    if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)) {
        WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(thirdPartyWebView.getSettings(), WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_ON);
    }
```

It doesn't matter if I call this in onViewCreated, onCreateView or onAttach of my Fragment the activity gets recreated which is visible by a blinking animation. If there a better way of setting dark mode in a webView (Why isn't it setting it automatically anyways?) or should I override the onConfigurationChange for uimode? -I think this is not recommended anymore?-